# SSMS 2016 Problems with the Editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express, management-studio-express, ssms-2016

I am facing problems with my SSMS express. I have installed a couple of windows 10 updates and after that I could not write queries anymore, the new query windows does not open. I can execute different operations with it such as Create object ("DB, Table, View, Function, etc.") but as long as SSMS tries to open a new query window the error is coming.

What I have done so far:

1. Uninstall / Install Management Studio (now I have the version 16.4.1)
2. Run repair tool for SSMS (once it finish say everything is in order)
3. Uninstall / Install SQL Server features and engine (is ok because is connecting to the server)

I have installed some of ApexSQL products and I did the same process (uninstall - try, install - try, reinstall - try).

Also as long as I open the "Text Editor" Options (Tools > Options >Text Editor > All Languages), SSMS stop working and restarts.

In these images you can see the trace of the error as well as the crashes once I click in the options.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KJ5o.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvuSp.png)

Thanks in advance

Diego